# Adding isChecked binding to a custom ToggleSwitch

Tags: c#, xaml, custom-controls, togglebutton

I have created a customer ToggleSwitch using this code and then changing the design to suit me.
[WPF toggleswitch code](https://mharwood.uk/apple-style-toggle-button-in-wpf/)

[image: Off]
[image: ON]

However when it loads on my page it looks like this:

[image]

I'm really new to this so i understand I've got a user based error that i literally dont understand however after hours I can't fix it!

I obviously need to make sure it loads with a checked value, however if I put `isChecked ="true"` in the xaml then it still loads like the unassigned picture.
In reality I have a setting "toggleDefault" in my code which I want to use on load of the form to say:

```
togContact = toggleDefault
```

However since I cant even get the XAML state to work, then this isnt working either.

Any suggestions would be great.

XAML custom code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    
    <Style x:Key="myToggleSwitch" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Viewbox>
                       
                            
                        
                            <Grid x:Name="toggleSwitch">
                            <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="10"
                        Background="#FFFFFFFF"
                        Width="80" Height="25">
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.5" Direction="0" Opacity="0.3" />
                                </Border.Effect>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Stretch="Uniform"
                             Margin="2 2 2 1"
                             Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.2"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="22" >
                                    <Ellipse.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="1" Opacity="0.3" Direction="260" />
                                    </Ellipse.Effect>
                                </Ellipse>
                            </Border>
                            
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txtOff" Text="OFF" Margin="0 0 8 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtOn" Text="ON" Margin="15 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold"  Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

                        </Grid>
                        
                            
                    
                    </Viewbox>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Checked">
                            
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                To="#34A543"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                    To="56 2 2 1"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtOff" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                                            From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1"     />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtOn" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                                            From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1"  />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Unchecked">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                To="#C2283B"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                    To="2 2 2 1"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtOff" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                                            From="0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1"       />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtOn" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                                            From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And below is my control code in the grid:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="togContact" IsChecked="true" Margin="5" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource myToggleSwitch}" />
```

EDIT:
I have tried adding this to XAML:

```
IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

This made no change.

I then tried setting isChecked to FALSE in the C# code.
This was interesting as it made the OFF appear in the UI on load.

I then tried changing isChecked to True in the c# code and i got an exception!

```
{"'Border' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate'."}
```

So I have obviously stuffed up the custom togglebutton code...

Comment: Hi Glenn, hope my answer helped you a little :-) Do you mind sharing your binding setup as well please if my answer hasn't helped?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the button is loading with the following styles:

```
 <Grid x:Name="toggleSwitch">
    <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="10"
    Background="#C2283B"
    Width="80" Height="25">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.5" Direction="0" Opacity="0.3" />
        </Border.Effect>
        <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Stretch="Uniform"
         Margin="2 2 2 1"
         Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.2"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="22" >
            <Ellipse.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="1" Opacity="0.3" Direction="260" />
            </Ellipse.Effect>
        </Ellipse>
    </Border>

    <TextBlock x:Name="txtOff" Text="OFF" Margin="0 0 8 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtOn" Opacity="0" Text="ON" Margin="15 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold"  Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

</Grid>
```

To have the toggle button load as either ON or OFF, you need to change the background colour of the border in the toggle switch and also either set the txtOff or txtOn `TextBlock` to have an `opacity` of 0.

The button below will load as red and OFF

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="myToggleSwitch" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Grid x:Name="toggleSwitch">
                            <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="10"
                    <!-- Background color here -->
                    Background="#C2283B" 
                    Width="80" Height="25">
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.5" Direction="0" Opacity="0.3" />
                                </Border.Effect>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Stretch="Uniform"
                         Margin="2 2 2 1"
                         Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.2"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="22" >
                                    <Ellipse.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="1" Opacity="0.3" Direction="260" />
                                    </Ellipse.Effect>
                                </Ellipse>
                            </Border>
                     
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtOff" Text="OFF" Margin="0 0 8 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White"/>
                            <!-- Opacity change here --> 
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtOn" Opacity="0" Text="ON" Margin="15 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold"  Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Checked">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            To="#34A543"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.1" />

                                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                To="56 2 2 1"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="txtOff" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                                        From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1"     />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="txtOn" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                                        From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1"  />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Unchecked">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            To="#C2283B"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                To="2 2 2 1"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="txtOff" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                                        From="0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1"       />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="txtOn" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                                        From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```